# Buildroot: syslog-ng logs into the "/var/log/messages.1" file instead of "/var/log/messages"

Tags: linux, embedded, buildroot, syslog-ng

I am building an embedded Linux board with Buildroot ([user manual here](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html)).

I have `syslog-ng` running on the board. It's config file is specified in buildroot here: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:

```
@version: 3.37

source s_sys {
    file("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel"));
    unix-stream ("/dev/log");
    internal();
};

destination d_all {
    file("/var/log/messages");
};

log {
    source(s_sys);
    destination(d_all);
};
```

Notice it specifies the destination as `"/var/log/messages"`, yet active logging on the board is going into a file named `/var/log/messages.1`, and the `/var/log/messages` file doesn't even exist. Why is that? Is there a way to get logging into the `/var/log/messages` file instead?

Syslog, which we used to use, logs into `/var/log/messages`, and we are trying to keep that behavior for consistency.

### Additional notes

1. `ls -1 /var/log` on a board running `syslog` contains these `messages` files:

   ```
   messages
   messages.1
   messages.2
   messages.2.gz
   messages.3
   messages.4
   messages.5
   messages.6
   messages.7
   ```
2. `ls -1 /var/log` on a board running `syslog-ng` contains these `messages` files (notice `messages` is missing):

   ```
   messages.1
   messages.2
   messages.3
   messages.4
   messages.5
   messages.6
   messages.7
   ```
3. On the `syslog-ng` board, `tail -f /var/log/messages.1` shows it is continually receiving logged messages, which is unexpected, since when using `syslog` the "active" file is `/var/log/messages` instead.

Comment: was the still-open logfile incorrectly rotated by logrotate or something like that?

Comment: @thrig, I don't know. Any way to check that? Maybe remove my logs and reboot to see how they get reconstructed?

Comment: restarting syslog-ng might be a simpler test, and finding out what all logrotate goes on on the system by default

Comment: @thrig, what's the best way to restart it? It seems to be started by Sysv Init at boot using this file here: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/syslog-ng/S01syslog-ng

Comment: read [this](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.37/administration-guide/110#TOPIC-1829338) - in the section `Use logrotate together with syslog-ng OSE` ... you need to somehow run the command `syslog-ng-ctl reload` after the messages file is rotated by `logrotate` ... (e.g. edit the `logrotate` config for `/var/log/messages`)

Comment: @MurrayJensen, thanks. I figured it out. That helped. I've added an answer. I've also opened up a documentation change request here: https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/4166. It is now recommended to use `syslog-ng-ctl reopen` after each log rotation instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved! You must force `syslog-ng` to reopen its target log files after each log rotation

So, I figured it out. Thanks to @Murray Jensen for [the hint about it here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717076/buildroot-syslog-ng-logs-into-the-var-log-messages-1-file-instead-of-var-l/717099#comment1359417_717076).

Whenever `logrotate` rotates my `/var/log/messages` file, it renames it to `/var/log/messages.1`. However, `syslog-ng` is writing to the file pointed to by the original file descriptor (fd) it opened up. Renaming the file from `/var/log/messages` to `/var/log/messages.1` does *not* change the file descriptor, so the file descriptor syslog-ng is now writing to points to the file now named `/var/log/messages.1`. **The fix is to simply force `syslog-ng` to reopen its log files and obtain new file descriptors after each log rotation, thereby causing it to obtain a new file descriptor for the newly-created target log file which now exists at `/var/log/messages`.**

There are 3 ways to do this, which I've written about here: https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/1774#issuecomment-1270517815

See here for where I learned about `syslog-ng-ctl reopen`, which is the recommended way: https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/1774#issuecomment-346624252

The 3 ways are:

```bash
# Option 0 (no longer recommended): call the heavier `reload` command after log
# rotation
syslog-ng-ctl reload

# Option 1 (RECOMMENDED): call the new `reopen` command after log rotation
syslog-ng-ctl reopen

# Option 2 (same thing as Option 1 above): send the `SIGUSR1` kill signal to the
# running `syslog-ng` process
pid="$(cat /var/run/syslog-ng.pid)" kill -SIGUSR1 $pid
```

So, to force `logrotate` to call one of the 3 ways above automatically after each log rotation, you must add the proper command as a `postrotate` script inside your `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng` (or similar--can be named anything) `logrotate` configuration file. Here is what a fixed logrotate config file might now look like:

[From my notes here:](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/1774#issuecomment-1270517815)

**Sample `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng` [logrotate](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html) config file:**

```bash
/var/log/auth.log 
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/messages  
{
    rotate 7
    size 20M
    delaycompress
    missingok
    # Required for syslog-ng after each rotation, to cause it to reopen log
    # files so it can begin logging to the new log file under a new file
    # descriptor, rather than to the old log file which has now been rotated
    # and renamed. 
    postrotate
        # After rotating the log files, cause syslog-ng to reopen the
        # destination log files so it will log into the newly-created log files
        # rather than into the now-rotated and renamed ones.
        #
        # This ensures, for example, that syslog-ng will move its file
        # descriptor to begin logging into the main "/var/log/messages" log
        # file again, instead of into the now-rotated "/var/log/messages.1"
        # file, which the old file descriptor (fd) is now pointing to since
        # that fd's filename was just renamed from "/var/log/messages"
        # to "/var/log/messages.1" during the log rotation.

        # Option 1:
        syslog-ng-ctl reopen
        # OR, Option 2
        # pid="$(cat /var/run/syslog-ng.pid)" kill -SIGUSR1 $pid
    endscript
}
```

Note: I've also opened up a documentation change request here: https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/4166. It is now recommended to use `syslog-ng-ctl reopen` after each log rotation instead of `syslog-ng-ctl reload`.

### Old attempt at an answer (what I tried first)

On the board running `syslog-ng`, I **reflashed the rootfs (root filesystem) image entirely**, and **rebooted the board**, and now I see the `/var/log/messages` file again:

Part of the output of `ls -1 /var/log`:

```
messages
messages.1
messages.2
messages.3
messages.4
messages.5
messages.6
messages.7
```

I can't explain it. `tail -f /var/log/messages` does indeed show active logs coming into that file, as expected, and `tail -f /var/log/messages.1` shows that the file is static, with no new messages coming in, also as expected.

I can prove that this board is indeed running `syslog-ng` by looking at the output of `ps aux | grep syslog`:

```bash
# ps aux | grep syslog
  803 root      0:00 {syslog-ng} supervising syslog-ng
  804 root      0:02 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng
12571 root      0:00 grep syslog
```

...as opposed to that same command's output when run on the `syslog` board:

```bash
# ps aux | grep syslog
  789 root      0:19 /sbin/syslogd -n -n -s 0
 2993 root      0:00 grep syslog
```

Again, I'm not sure what happened, nor why.

On both boards, `ps aux | grep logrotate` shows that `logrotate` is running. Ex:

```bash
# ps aux | grep logrotate
 1299 root      0:00 runsv logrotate-periodically
14208 root      0:00 grep logrotate
```

Both boards have the same `/etc/logrotate.conf` file, and only the `syslog-ng` board has the `/etc/syslog-ng.conf` file, which contains the contents as shown in the question.

If I figure out anything new in the coming days, I'll come back and update this answer.